# kubernetes not able to pull pictures for ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes

I have a very simple ruby on rails application that I dockerized and i am trying to put the docker image in kubernetes. If I run just the container, I am able to see the default ruby on rails welcome screen with the default pictures. When I put the docker image into kubernetes, the pictures do not appear, as well as if I try to access its api end points I get connection time outs.

I have tried adding egress to the network policy but seems to completely cutoff access to the application. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapi
  namespace: "test"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testapi
    spec:
      securityContext:
        containers:
        - name: testapi
          image: some/location
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapi
  namespace: "test"
  annotations:
    k8s.ikarem.io/update-dns: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    app: testapi
ports:
- protocol: TCP
  port: 3000
  targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: some-policy
  namespace: "test"
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapi
  ingress:
    - from: []
  egress: // I removed this and I can access the application, with this I have no access.
    - to: []
```

Comment: please share how you are exposing your API and edpoints, are you using any ingress or service type LoadBalancer ?

Comment: Thank you @HarshManvar I added my service on my question. For the API endpoints , do you want the route I created on the rails app? I am able to access the api when I just run the docker container

Comment: Share you deployment spec have added container port ?

Comment: @HarshManvar I added the full kubernetes yml with the deployment spec